# Synchronize periodic Task with another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following situation in a Game i'm working:

```
class GameLogic implements Runnable
{
    State state;

    private State changeState()
    {
        //state changes here (note the `private`)
    }

    // this ticks at each 0.5 seconds
    public void run()
    {
      //code that changes state
      changeState();
    }

    // this will be called by a external Thread at any moment
    public void update(Move move)
    {
       //code that changes state
       applyMove(move);
    }

    private void applyMove(Move move)
    {
         //state changes here
         //state = ... doesn't matter
    }

}
```

The run method above is scheduled to execute at each 0.5 seconds, using a *Timer* or a *ScheduledExecutorService*.

The problem is the `update` method, will be called by another Thread at any moment. So i ask:

1 - What happens if a use `synchronized` to protect the  `state` field? The timer will wait? How it will compensate for the 'waiting period'?

2 - Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe storing the  `moves` on some queue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both `Timer` and `ScheduledExecutorService` can execute tasks at *fixed rates* or with *fixed delays* between executions. That means, a scheduled task with *fixed rates* will compensate the running time (including blocking time) of the execution. A scheduled task with *fixed delays* will not. See the documentation of the following methods for more information:

   - *Fixed rate:* [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) and [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)
   - *Fixed delay:* [Timer.schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) and [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)
2. There is always a better way. However, the solution looks fine. And as long as it works for you, go with it.

Comment: Thanks! Actually my problem is a little bit more complicated, but i made the question as simple as possible. I'll ran some tests then come back with and edit if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An additional way to deal with this problem is by having the updates coming in from the updating thread go to a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) or something similar. This way, on each iteration of the state being adjusted you can grab all of the updates from the queue and apply them in the same thread.

Using this method, there would never be any conflict between the updating thread and the game loop thread.

Personally, I would use a while loop that takes advantage of some regulating mechanism instead of scheduling anything. You can use [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) in order to apply your updates using time deltas. This would ensure that the execution of logic is not bound to the machine's performance.

There's a brilliant article on the topic [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_4_%28Timing%29).

Comment: Yep, i also thought about doing that, now i have to decide which way to go.